# Is it possible to access an IOS Device from Windows PC without Itunes

Tags: c#, ios, iphone

I have C Sharp Application on a Windows PC and I want to connect an IOS Device(e.g. IPad Air) via usb cable.
Now I want my C Sharp Application to recognize the IOS Device and transmit some data to this device.
Is my intention feasible in any way ?? If it is possible what is the best way to do this?

Thanky you

Answer (score 1):

maybe this information could you help

> jPhone was a Windows application which allowed the user to mount the file system of an iOS device (iPhone, iPad) as a hard drive. The idea behind jPhone was to make it possible for jPod to support managing the media libraries of iOS devices. jPhone was written in C#  https://code.google.com/p/jphonewin/

Reference: http://jonathan.bergknoff.com/projects/jphone

Good luck !!!

Comment: Sounds nice, but this access seems to be like a jailbrake, I can't use an unsupport and maybe even illegal connection. It is for business use

Comment: Doesn't work, probably too old...